# Why is module global assignment different simple types vs classes/dictionaries?

Tags: python

Given the following example code:

test.py

```
import module

print 'main: Vars.foo: %s' % (module.Vars.foo)
print 'main: d.foo: %s' % (module.d['foo'])
print 'main: foo: %s' % (module.foo)
print
module.Vars.foo = 2
module.d['foo']=2
module.foo = 2

def baz():
    print 'baz: Vars.foo: %s' % (module.Vars.foo)
    print 'baz: d.foo: %s' % (module.d['foo'])
    print 'baz: foo: %s' % (module.foo)
    print
    module.bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    baz()
```

module/
    module.py
    `__init__.py`

`__init__.py`

```
from module import *
```

module.py

```
class Vars:
    foo = None
d = {'foo': None}
foo = None

def bar():
    print 'bar: Vars.foo: %s' % (Vars.foo)
    print 'bar: d.foo: %s' % (d['foo'])
    print 'bar: foo: %s' % (foo)
```

produces this output when test.py is run:

```
main: Vars.foo: None
main: d.foo: None
main: foo: None

baz: Vars.foo: 2
baz: d.foo: 2
baz: foo: 2

bar: Vars.foo: 2
bar: d.foo: 2
bar: foo: None
```

All of this makes sense to me except the bar() output. Why is the bar() output different for a class/dictionary vs. a simple type? I think it has something to do with the mutability of a class/dictionary but I'm not sure. What I'm specifically looking for is the actual python language rules that are causing that bar output to be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you are mutating `Vars` and `d`, but you're just assigning a new value to `foo`.

You have made your example somewhat confusing by naming your package and module both "module".  This is misleadng because although both your imports appear to import from `module`, they don't import from the same file.  I'm going to rename your stuff like this for explanation:

```
package/
    module.py
    __init__.py
```

The import in `test.py` then becomes `import package` (because `test.py` is outside of the package, so the only thing it can directly import is the package).  But the import in `__init__.py` is still `from module import *` (because it is importing from another module in the same package).

When `test.py` does `import package`, then, what it imports is the `__init__.py` of the package.  Some stuff is available in that `__init__.py` because `__init__.py` did `from module import *`.  However, `from module import *`creates a new namespace holding all the stuff from `module.py`.  Mutating the objects will cause effects no matter how you access them, but assigning new values to the names will only affect that one namespace.

Then, when you do `package.Vars.foo = 2`, you mutate the class object.  When you do `package.d['foo'] = 2`, you mutate the dict object.  But when you do `package.foo = 2`, you are just assigning a new name to the value `foo` in `__init__.py`.  (Or, to look at it another way, you are mutating the module object for `__init__.py`.)  This leaves the original variable `foo` in `module.py` unaffected.

The function `bar` sees the mutations to `Vars` and `d`, but it is accessing the variable `d` in its own namespace, not the namespace of `__init__.py`, so it does no see any new values that were assigned to `package.foo`.

In short, the behavior you see is basically the same as this:

```
x = {'foo': None}
y = None

a = x
b = y

a['foo'] = 2
b = 2
```

After this `x` will be `{'foo': 2}`, but `y` will still be None.  Why?  Because `a['foo'] = 2` mutates the object referred to by `a`; since `x` refers to that same object, it "sees" the mutation.  But `b = 2` just assigns a new name to `b`.  This is the same as what is going on in your example; it's just slightly harder to see because the mutations and assignments are happening in different namespaces.

Comment: More in-depth explanation than mine.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation makes a lot of sense to me. I didn't think about the fact that the import in `__init__.py` was a different namespace than module.py.

Answer (score 1):

In test.py you are importing the `module` *package*, not the `module.module` *module*. In this package's `__init__.py` you're doing a star import from the `module.module` module. So when you rebind `module.foo` in test.py, it's the package's 'foo' you are rebinding, not the module's one. Wrt/ the other objects, you are mutating them, not rebinding them, which is a different operation.

If in test.py you replace `import module` with `from module import module` you'll get a different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`from module import *` creates new variables in `__init__.py`'s namespace and assigns the referenced objects from `module`. These references see the objects but don't know anything about the other references to the object.

`Vars` references the `module.Vars` class so a change to one if its child attributes is seen by all. `d` references the `module.d` dict so changes to the mutable object are seen by all. In both cases, the referenced object was changed, not the variable itself.

In the case of `foo`, you are reassigning the local variable called `foo`, not the object that it references.